# Shell script: if condition not evaluating properly

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have below script.

```
echo "CURMTHY" $CURMTHY     //This prints the value 10
if [ $CURMTHY -eq 01 ]
echo "inside if"
then PRVMTHY=12
     PRVYRY=`expr $CURYRY - 1`
else PRVMTHY=`expr $CURMTHY - 1`
    echo "inside else"
     PRVYRY=$CURYRY
fi
```

Instead of entering the `else` condition, it is entering the `if` condition. Though `CURMTHY` variable is holding value 10
why is it satisfying the condition of 01?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "CURMTHY" "$CURMTHY"

if [ "$CURMTHY" -eq 1 ]; then
   echo "inside if"
   PRVMTHY=12
   PRVYRY=$(expr $CURYRY - 1)
else
   PRVMTHY=$(expr $CURMTHY - 1)
   echo "inside else"
   PRVYRY="$CURYRY"
fi
```

Don't put a command before `then` and use `$(...)` for command substitution.